# how to apply skip and limit filters in controller on Laravel API

Tags: php, laravel

## **This is My controller Index method.**
    How can I apply filters for this method. Here bookFormat method is custom method to get results. Thanks in advance.

```
public function index(){
        $input = Input::only('skip','limit'); 
        $books = Book::all();
        $results = [];
        foreach ($books as $book) {
         $results [] = $this->bookFormat($book);
     } 
     $skip = null;
     if(isset($input['skip'])){
        $skip = $input['skip'];
     return $results->skip($skip); 
     }
      $limit = null;
     if(isset($input['limit'])){
        $limit = $input['limit'];
        return $results->limit($limit)->get();
     }
     return $results;
 }
```

Comment: Although it is not clear at the first glance. You should also add more details like in which condition you are not getting proper result.

Comment: And also share what does `$this->bookFormat()` do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by checking `isset` and at last apply `skip,take` or `limit,offset`.

```
public function index(){
    $input = Input::only('skip','limit');
    $query = new Book();
    if(isset($input['skip']) && $input['skip']){
        $query = $query->skip($input['skip']);
    }
    if(isset($input['limit']) && $input['limit']){
        $query = $query->take($input['limit']);
    }

    $books = $query->get();

    $results = [];
    foreach ($books as $book) {
        $results [] = $this->bookFormat($book);
    }
    return $results;
}
```

OR you can use `Request $request` to get `skip` and `limit` value

```
public function index(Request $request){
    $skip = (isset($request->skip) && $request->skip) ? $request->skip : '';
    $limit = (isset($request->limit) && $request->limit) ? $request->limit : '';
    .......................
    .......................
}
```

Comment: How you are calling this method ? And passing both params ?

Comment: Also check value like `isset($input['skip']) && $input['skip']`

Comment: public function index()
    {
       $input = Input::only('skip','limit'); 
       $skip = isset($input['skip'])?$input['skip']:0;
       $take = isset($input['limit'])?$input['limit']:0;
       $books = Book::skip($skip)->take($take)->get();
        $results = [];
        foreach ($books as $book) {
        $results [] = $this->bookFormat($book);
     } 
      return $results;

Comment: Just check with direct value of `skip` and `limit` ? And let me know ?

Comment: If it's not solved then please revert this answer as unaccepted , to get others attention to come and give their suggestion.